# C++ new in function argument

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, reference

I'm trying to build some network flow algorithms, and I need to represent edges in graph.

this is my Edge structure:

```
struct Edge{
  int from, to, flow, cap;
  Edge(int fromC, int toC, int flowC , int capC)
    : from(fromC), to(toC), flow(flowC), cap(capC)
  {};
};
```

then I have graph structure with adjacency list:

```
struct Graph {
  int N;
  vector<vector<Edge> > adjList;  // list of neighbours    

  Graph(int n) {                  // constructor
    N=n;
    adjList.resize(n);
  }
};
```

and then I have function to add edges to adjacency list:

```
void addEdge ( Graph &G, Edge &E)
{
  G.adjList[E.from-1].push_back(E);
}
```

and I want to use **this syntax:**

```
Graph G = Graph(4);  // creates graph with4 vertices
addEdge(G, new Edge(2, 4, 0, 4));
```

but this doesn`t work… I have to change function to:

```
 void addEdge(Graph &G, Edge *E)
```

and then modify everything in function body…

My question is: 
Is there a way to use new in function call with references like ?:

```
addEdge(G, new Edge(2, 4, 0, 4));
```

Thank you for your answers. ( I'm new to C++, sorry if answer is obvious: No, you have to use pointers in signature & body... )

Comment: Why do you want to use `new` like that?

Comment: because otherwise I'd have to use `Edge e =Edge(1,3,0,4);  addEdge(G, e );` which are 2 lines of code, or 2m lines where m is number of lines

Comment: That's a very poor reason to use dynamic allocation. What you need to do is change the function to `void addEdge(Graph &G, const Edge& E)` and then say `addEdge(G, Edge(1, 3, 0, 4));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `new` and have `addEdge` accept a `const Edge&`. This lets you simply use an automatic temporary like this:

```
addEdge(G, Edge(2,4,0,4));
```

`addEdge`'s signature becomes `void addEdge(Graph &G, const Edge &E)`.

Comment: As I said, it had to be pretty obvious, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write just:

```
addEdge(G, Edge(2,4,0,4));
```

But you should consider performance issues. This form creates temporary instance on the stack, so you are supposed to do a copy (push_back alreade does).

Comment: _"so you are supposed to do a copy"_ a _move constructor/assignment operator_ for `Edge` can finally heal this.

Comment: Yes, but it stil can produce more overhead than handling with pointer. It depends on use case what way is more suitable for solving a problem.

Comment: _"Yes, but it stil can produce more overhead than handling with pointer."_ How actually?

Comment: For example if you need Edges outside of Graph for some reason. But you are right, you can return pointer to adjList[x] in this case.

Comment: This is nonsense. A copy, which will probably be optimised out or replaced with a move anyway, is almost certainly cheaper here than the overhead of dynamic allocation _and_ all the locality/cache issues that come with a container of pointers. Not to mention the overhead in your code of later freeing it all, and of deep copying the vector.

Answer (score -1):

Declare `addEdge` to take a `const` reference since you're not modifying the original object.

Then you can simply do this:

```
void addEdge ( Graph &G, const Edge &E) { ... }
addEdge(G, Edge(2,4,0,4));
```

This is the preferred way in C++, since it avoids dynamic allocation.

Comment: That won't work, because the function's second parameter is a non-const lvalue reference. That can't bind to a temporary.

Comment: My guess is that modifying a temporary was deemed too dangerous/nonsensical to allow this binding.

Comment: Actually the "preferred way" is code that compiles.

Comment: @zenith: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/560648 (tl;dr: it's fairly weak as far as rationales go)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, that was a good read. Fixed my answer.